# What are some examples of functions that are continous from $[a,b]$, differentiable $(a,b)$ but not at $a$ and $b$.

Tags: calculus

I am studying the MVT and Rolle's Theorem. I would like some examples of functions that are continuous from $[a,b]$, differentiable from $(a,b)$ but not differentiable at $a$ and $b$. I am aware that the derivative at the point c is defined as:

$ f'(c) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$

Basically, I'm wondering why does a function have to be continuous at the endpoints of the interval, but it doesn't have to be differentiable at the endpoints. Why is this important?

My other question is, how significant is the study of open/closed sets important in calculus?

Comment: *how significant is the study of open/closed sets important in calculus?* Well, it is more like an advanced version of open/closed intervals.

Comment: Note that the limit you've written doesn't exist at $a$ and $b$ as the function isn't defined in an open neighbourhood of those points.

Comment: Note that although differentiability at the end points is not necessary for the MVT to apply, it doesn't hurt. Theorems tend to provide the reader with all the *strictly necessary conditions*. Differentiability at the end points is nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$f(x)=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ on $[-a,+a]$ or $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ on $[0,b],~b>0$

Comment: $\Large\color{green}{✔}^\color{red}{+}$Babak S.

Comment: ${+1^{+1}}^{+ 1} \ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Another example is f(x)=x*sin(1/x)  on [0,1] note here there is no derivative at x=0 not even if we allow infinity.

Comment: By x*sin(1/x) you mean $x\cdot \sin\frac1x$? (It is kind of confusing since it seems like x with $*$ in exponent. The same expression would look somewhat better in math mode: $f(x)=x*\sin(1/x)$.)

Answer (score 0):

The function must be continuous at the endpoints of the interval as otherwise you could just pick f(a), f(b) arbitrarily and get crazy results.